# Correct settings for Dragon Ball Budokai Tenkaichi 3 on PCSX2?

Tags: technical-issues, ubuntu, pcsx2, dragon-ball-z-budokai-tenkaichi-3

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 to play *Dragon Ball Z: Budokai Tenkaichi 3* on PCSX2. When I try to play the game, the text gets blurry and the 3D environment fails to render. I think it's only matter of configuring it correctly.

I am using: PCSX2 v1.4.0 with GSDx 1.0 (GCC 4.8.4), PS2 BIOS USA v1.6

What settings should I be using for *Budokai Tenkaichi 3*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [this page](http://wiki.pcsx2.net/index.php/Dragon_Ball_Z:_Budokai_Tenkaichi_3) will help you out. There are configurations for Windows, and conveniently, an Ubuntu build, however it is only for the PAL version.

Settings are as follows:

### Graphics

- GSdx (GCC 4.9.1, SSE2) 0.1.16 [libGSdx-0.1.16]

### Sound

- SPU2-X 2.0.0 [libspu2x-2.0.0]

### Pad

- OnePAD 0-Dev 1.1.0 [libonepad-1.1.0]

### Comments

(copied verbatim)

- Tested with BIOS: Europe v02.30, Japan v02.20.
- Audio Synchronization: Async Mix.
- Working Status: Good.
- Minor video glitches during close combat attacks.

Now, the windows configurations do mention using Speedhacks and the like, and playing around with those until you get a suitably working emulation. Bear in mind, however, that emulation is not yet perfected, and sometimes games will simply refuse to work, either correctly or at all.

Comment: Nope bro, it didn't work http://imageshack.com/a/img922/7061/I8rShY.png |
http://imageshack.com/a/img923/1152/NDtccd.png |
http://imageshack.com/a/img924/3331/wmpulq.png |
http://imageshack.com/a/img922/7639/tY3MBa.png

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar Like I said, there's no guarantees with emulation.